# Android draw a picture on top of this picture (dynamicaly)

Tags: android, dynamic, view, imageview, repaint

I have RelativeLayout with ImageView.

I want to click on the picture and add the same picture on top. It must be dynamically, without calling onCreate method. It's red circle (transparent 10% - *.png)

Like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGOhn.png]

How best to do this?

Comment: If you want it when touching the screen. Add it to the onTouchEvent(). There are many events you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the alpha value of the origion picture every time.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.my_picture);       
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(CURRENT_VALUE);
canvas.drawBitmap(botmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

or direcly with an ImageView

```
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);
myImageView.setAlpha(xxx);
```

Comment: increase alpha of 100%-visibility image? I didn't know how to do this, can u tell?

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you need to do this?  There are a couple of ways depending upon your needs.  First, if you only need to do it once.  Put the image on top of the first image in your layout but set its visibility to invisible.  Then when you click on the image, change the visibility to visible.

The second way if you need to do it repeatedly is to place the image view in a separate layout, use  in the primary layout for the fist image then load the imageview using a layoutinflater in your code.

After the rest of your info, I moved my comment up here:
Just increase the alpha value of the image.

Comment: I need to do this 100 times maximum. The circle will have 1% of visibility. Each click add overlay image and add each % to visibility of image.

Comment: Why would you load it multiple times then?  You should instead just modify the alpha of the image to increment it every time it is clicked.

Comment: Make the image full visibility.  Then when it is initially loaded, set the alpha to 1% or about 2 since alpha goes from 0-255,  then increase alpha by 2 or 3 each click until it gets to 255.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test extends Activity {


RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

 ImageView imageView1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);



    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            imageView1=new ImageView(Test.this);

            imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageView.getLayoutParams());



            //imageView1=imageView;

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });

            imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow1);
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView1);
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "NEW IMAGE", 1).show();
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "OLD IMAGE", 1).show();

            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imageView=null;


        }
    } 
    );
```

XML LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/aboutus_h" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will help you to get your work done.